# ffmpeg: symbol lookup error (Linux mint MATE 21.1, Kernel 6.1.0-1010-oem )

Tags: linux-mint, ffmpeg

I'm currently struggling to get ffmpeg working again and it cripples my ability to either use discord or watch mp4s in firefox.

Trying to use ffmpeg in the console returns:

```
cla@CLAX1:~$ ffmpeg
ffmpeg: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-x11.so.2: undefined symbol: va_fool_postp
```

and discord:

```
la@CLAX1:~$ discord
discord: error while loading shared libraries: libffmpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've searched many days for possible solutions, but to no avail. It is commonly recommended to install libva-x11-2:i386 but that didn't work out either. There were suggestions to mess with systemlinks, but that worsened things temporarily.

I want to thank for any advice in advance.